# Monitoring Application Network Traffic in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've been searching for this for a while, but is there a way to monitor the network traffic coming/going from a specific application using the appliances that are already built into the Qt library?  I've found some solutions using things like WinPCap and other similar utilities, but I was hoping to keep it all in the Qt (in C++) house as that is what I am most familiar with.

Thanks!  Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your platform? If it is on Windows then WinPCap is the only way. To sniff network packets you need a kernel space driver or something like that. Qt has no such functionality.

Comment: Assuming you are able to modify the Qt application, would it be sufficient to put wrapper functions around the read() and write() calls that track the number of bytes being sent/received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some example of c# sniffer socket creation.

```
    mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw,
                           ProtocolType.IP);

    // Bind the socket to the selected IP address
    mainSocket.Bind(newIPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text),0));

    // Set the socket options
    mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                               SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                               true);                           //option to true

    byte[] byTrue = newbyte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0};
    byte[] byOut = newbyte[4];

    //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
    mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  //SIO_RCVALL of Winsock
                         byTrue, byOut);

    //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
    mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                            newAsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

May be qt provides some api for creating such sockets.After creating such socket you'll get raw pacets on it parsing headers and other info is on you.